# use outside air for combustion for gas dryer? why not install in airtight closet,with fresh air intake vent?

Tags: dryer, gas

instead of using your heater or cooled air you've paid $$ for ,why not use outside air for combustion of your  Gas  dryer? Install the dryer in an airtight closet install a  vent for  fresh air that the dryer would  pull  in and of course the normal exhaust gas dryer venting. I'll bet you'd save enough in lower heating  and  cooling  costs to make it worth  the one time trouble.  Any ideas??

Comment: The exhaust air is not suitable for breathing though, especially if a malfunction causes it to produce CO

Comment: @ratchetfreak -- he's still venting the exhaust air to the outside.  what he's talking about would basically be a step towards a sealed combustion gas dryer...

Comment: Where I live it would need to be a dedicated room without the washer, unless heat was provided to keep the washer and its plumbing from freezing.

Comment: in the winter, you're paying to heat the drying air no matter what, either halfway with your furnace or all the way with the dryer. in the summer w/AC, your idea makes sense since heat is bad then, but the "cold" air is also much drier and not a whole lot cooler than outside, which probably means your drier will run for less time with AC'd air intake. in short; seems like a wash.

Answer (score 2):

In the winter, up north where I live, that would not be a good idea since the air I would need for combustion and to dry the clothes would be extremely cold and would slow up the drying process and require the dryer to run longer. Dryers use a lot of air for both drying the clothes and for the combustion of the nat gas. Also I like the fact that running the dryer will exchange some of the homes air helping to keep the home's atmosphere fresh. Some seemingly good ideas are probably just too good for me. There would probably be no cost savings after this investment.

Comment: Yeah, -30F makes this sort of thing less than ideal.